# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements. error

Tags: ios, visual-studio, icloud

Please help me understand what I'm missing when setting up iCloud testing for the sample iCloudUIApp.
https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/IntroductionToiCloud/iCloudUIDoc

The sample app uploads to a physical device just fine without iCloud being enabled (crashes, but that's OK) which means that Provisioning Profile, Devices, Team ID, App ID are set correctly.

Now, as soon as I enable iCloud in Entitlements.plist it gives me this error:
'error MT1006: Could not install the application'
and
'The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.'

Here is what I did:

- I set up an iCloud Container in Developer portal with the ID: iCloud.com.sketch.iCloudUIDoc
- I added iCloud Application Service to the App ID in Developer portal (Also non-optionally enabled are In-App Purchase and Game Center)
- I set iCloud Container Assignment to iCloud.com.sketch.iCloudUIDoc and enabled it

in Visual Studio:

- in the Entitlements.plist I enable iCloud
- Services: I enable iCloud Documents and CloudKit
- I set Containers to: iCloud.com.sketch.iCloudUIDoc (also tried with Team ID as prefix - to no avail)

In Info.plist I have Team, Signing Certificate, Provisioning Profile set up with Automatic signing management enabled.
No other services are enabled here (Background Modes, GameCenter, Maps).

Device:

- signed in to iCloud
- iCloud Drive enabled
- iCloud access for iCloudUIDoc app is enabled

Run the app -> uploading error.
Tried with different hardware - same result.

What do I get wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it's not enough to download and dbl click .mobileprovisioning files on the Apple Developer site - I also needed to goto to Visual Studio - Preferences - Apple Developer Accounts - View Details - Download All Profiles.
After that it worked.

I hope it helps someone out there stuck in this loop.